# pymongo syntax to update a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My documents look like this:

```
{
  a: "..."
  subdocs [
    {
      l: "..."
      m: "..."
      n: 0
    },
    {
      l: "..."
      m: "..."
      n: 0
    }

  }
}
```

I have to update the 'n' field in a particular subdoc using pymongo.  I have the document and the index of the subdocument so I can get the subdoc like this

```
subdoc = mydoc['subdocs'][index]
```

I try to do an update through pymongo

```
coll.update( { mydoc['subdocs'][index] : subdoc }, { "$inc": { n: 1 }} )
```

I get this exception

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
```

I've tried several variations on this and can't get the pymongo syntax right.  I think my query document is incorrect.  What does pymongo expect for this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the array element to update in the second parameter to `update` using dot notation like this:

```py
coll.update({'_id': mydoc['_id']}, {'$inc': {'subdocs.' + str(index) + '.n': 1}})
```